# SQL GROUP BY: Getting the most recently updated record for an indexed view

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by, indexed-view

I'm trying to do row versioning using an indexed view, grouping records by their key and timestamp, and taking the max(timestamp) record. This is fine, but the query I have used (see the view below) does a self join, meaning it can't be used in an indexed view, which i think will be essential to performance. Is there a way to rewrite the query so the view can be created successfully WITH SCHEMABINDING?

I'm using 2005, but a 2008 only solution would be fine too.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.views WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[Items]'))
    DROP VIEW [dbo].[Items]
GO
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[ItemHistory]') AND type in (N'U'))
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[ItemHistory]
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ItemHistory](
    [Key] [nchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [Value] [int] NOT NULL,
    [TimeStamp] Timestamp NOT NULL,
    [LastUpdateBy] [varchar](50) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_ItemHistory_LastUpdateBy]  DEFAULT (SUSER_NAME()),
    [Deleted] BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT (0)
    CONSTRAINT [PK_ItemHistory] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [Key] ASC,
        [TimeStamp] ASC
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
)
GO
CREATE VIEW dbo.Items
--WITH SCHEMABINDING --doesnt work with the query below :(
AS
    SELECT ih.[key], ih.[Value] FROM ItemHistory ih
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT [Key], Max([TimeStamp]) [TimeStamp]
        FROM ItemHistory
        GROUP BY [Key]
    ) ih2 ON ih.[key] = ih2.[key] AND ih.[TimeStamp] = ih2.[TimeStamp] AND Deleted = 0
GO 
INSERT INTO Items ([Key], [Value]) VALUES ('ItemA', 1)
INSERT INTO Items ([Key], [Value]) VALUES ('ItemA', 2)
INSERT INTO Items ([Key], [Value]) VALUES ('ItemA', 3)

GO
SELECT * FROM ItemHistory
SELECT * FROM Items
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you replace `ItemHistory` with `dbo.ItemHistory` in the `Items` view definition it should work.

Also you might find the following query performs better as it avoid the use of the `MAX` function.

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.Items
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
    SELECT ih.[key], ih.[Value] FROM dbo.ItemHistory ih
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT [Key]
        FROM dbo.ItemHistory AS ih2
        WHERE ih.[key] = ih2.[key] AND ih.[TimeStamp] < ih2.[TimeStamp]) AND Deleted = 0
GO
```

Comment: You sir, are a genius. I sir, am an idiot. Didn't read the create message properly.

Would 
 SELECT ih.[key], ih.[Value] FROM dbo.ItemHistory ih
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 [Key]
        FROM dbo.ItemHistory AS ih2
        WHERE ih.[key] = ih2.[key] AND ih.[TimeStamp] < ih2.[TimeStamp]
  ORDER BY Timestamp desc)
perform even better?

Comment: You are far too kind. I'm not sure if the additional TOP 1 clause would make it faster as SQL Server performs lots of optimizations behind the scenes and in fact the execution plans are identical. As another example there is no difference, as far as I am aware, between using SELECT * and SELECT [Key] for the sub query in terms of execution speed as SQL Server is only interested in whether or not a row exists.